# 5.64.4 - Event Registration price total not displaying

Tags: civievent, drupal, price-sets, drupal-7

We've just installed version 5.64.4 with Drupal 7 and price totals on event registration forms are no longer displaying if using the Regular Fees options (pre-defined pricesets seem to be working fine)

Anyone else experiencing this issue?

Best wishes
Jonny

Comment: Where do you mean specifically? On the first page, the review page or the confirmation page? Can you add a screenshot?